# Need a separate table to cache top 10 scores for leaderboard (MongoDB)?

Tags: mongodb, database-design, schema, backend

I have a question of following situation:

I already have a score table storing the best score for each game for each user. Roughly one user has about 10 rows in score table for 10 games' top score of that user. If I want to get the overall top 10 user for leaderboard, theoretically I could directly query score table. But I am worrying about if there are too many users in score table and many users are query the top 10 at the same time,  will the query on the server take too long?

Is it worth to create a separate table to cache overall top 10 users for each game so that the caching table size is fixed and query time will not scale up as user number scales up? I could update the caching table like every one hour.

I am not sure different database may be different on this or not. Now I am using MongoDB, provided by Parse.comd Server. I might transfer to other database later(like MySql).

Comment: Your "top 10 overall" request for a single game can be handled efficiently with your current table. The important thing here is that you create an efficient index on this field. So for example if your fields were game and score, your index could be: {game: 1, score: -1} where you are indexing game ascending and score descending. Looking up the top 10 records would just be a matter of an indexed game lookup followed by traversing the top 10 scores. For  an overview of indexing in MongoDB see: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/indexes/

Comment: To add, using a limit on that query with the sorted index for the top 10 means that you should only ever have to actually scan 10 entries, in fact you could probably make this into a covered query, not only that but as it scales up you could look into storing either all of one game on a single node (super fast querying but can cause hotspots) or could make a compound between game and score

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly recommend looking into caching for a score board.

You've already seen that with a lot of users and a lot of games, keeping the top scores board current and accurate will become more and more expensive over time.

You could use Mongo to pre-process results and store them in a different collection, but you might also consider using something like Couchbase (http://www.couchbase.com/), Memcached (http://memcached.org/) or Redis (http://redis.io/) to cache your data.

A good approach for caching the scores ...

1. For a top 10 list for all users for a given game, set the cache expiration from 1-5 minutes. So after 5 minutes it will run your Mongo query and refresh the cache. You'll have to decide how fresh you want that data to be.
2. For a user's own high score board ... cache it for days. You can pro-actively expire it when they have finished a game and have a new high score. Only then will you refresh it.

The idea is identifying which pieces of data need to be pro-actively expired and which can expire on their own.

Also as a note I would recommend trying as hard as possible to make everything expire on its own. Much easier to manage.

Answer (score 0):

Thats its exactlly what i will do in the game im creating, since i have multiple game levels (easy,medium, hard) i need to store those top 10 for each level. To reduce the number of api calls to parse.com i will create a cloud background job on parse that runs every 5 minutes to create a cache table with top 10 for each level, and on my client app i just select this entire cache table with 30 records with one api call.